# wso2 : How to handle access to inactive service fault message?

Tags: wso2, endpoint, fault, wso2-esb

**How can i handle fault message results in access to inactive service?**

I have N endpoint. in insequence send the message to endpint1 and set OnError of Insequece to Seqerhandler. in Seqerhandler i send message to another endpoint. when i set endpoint key to mistake key message pass to seqerhandler but when i inactive endpoint1 using Jconsole message does not pass to seqerhandler and send fault message below to client.

```
 <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>

     <faultstring>The system is attempting to access an inactive service
```

how can i handle this fault message by Seqerhandler same another fault?

please guide me!

Comment: Can you include example configuration here?

Answer (score 0):

Fault handlers will be executed only for mediation errors not for endpoint errors.
For endpoint error handling follow [this guide](http://wso2.org/library/articles/wso2-enterprise-service-bus-endpoint-error-handling);